# ($rootScope:inprog) $apply already in progress

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I'm trying apply changes to ui grid after refreshing data but getting this error:

```
    angular.js:13236 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
        at angular.js:68
        at beginPhase (angular.js:17178)
        at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16616)
        at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16928)
        at Scope.$scope.submitForm (app-controllers.js:652)
        at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14086), <anonymous>:4:335)
        at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15076)
        at callback (angular.js:24546)
        at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16820)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16920)
```

What can be wrong? my code below

get data

```
    var initialData = [] 
var getData = function (castomUrl) {
                $http.get(castomUrl)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        // console.log(data)
                        // Considering Angular UI-Grid, the data should be declared inside as scope var and put it inside gridOptions
                        $scope.initialData = data;
                        // $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.initialData;
                        // ***
                        angular.forEach($scope.initialData, function (val) {
                            val.occuredDate = new Date(val.occuredDate);
                        });
                        // $interval whilst we wait for the grid to digest the data we just gave it
                        $interval(function () {
                            $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.initialData[0]);
                        }, 0, 1);
                    });
            };
            getData(urlData);
```

get row value by click

```
     gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
                        // api call to get row Data and update for current row
                        var dataRow = row.entity;
                        $scope.id = dataRow.id;
                        $scope.getRowData();
                    });

 $scope.getRowData = function(){
                eventService.singleEvent($scope.id)
                    .then(function (data) {
                        $scope.rowData = data.model;
                        $scope.rowKeys = Object.keys($scope.rowData);
                    }).then(function () {
                    $scope.getUpdate();
                });
            };
```

where eventService.singleEvent is

```
 function singleEvent (id) {
            return $http.get(apiUrl+id)
                        .then(function (serviceResp) {
                           return serviceResp.data;
                        });
        }
```

display row data as form html

```
  <form style="padding: 15px" ng-submit="submitForm(rowData)">
                                    <div class="form-group row">

                                        <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in rowData">
                                            <div ng-if="(key === 'id' || key.toLowerCase().endsWith('id') === false) ? true : false">
                                                <label for="rowData" class="col-sm-2">{{key | makeUppercase
                                                    }}</label>
                                                <div class=" col-sm-2">
                                                    <input class="form-control rowValue"
                                                           id="rowData[key]"
                                                           ng-disabled="disableInput(key)"
                                                           ng-if="!isObject(value)"
                                                           type="text"
                                                           ng-model="rowData[key]"
                                                    />
                                                    <input
                                                            class="form-control rowValue"
                                                            id="rowData[key].name"
                                                            ng-disabled="disableInput(key)"
                                                            ng-if="isObject(value) && key !== 'status' && key !== 'priority' && key !== 'severity'"
                                                            type="text"
                                                            ng-model="rowData[key].name"
                                                    />
                                                    <select ng-if="isObject(value) && key == 'status'"
                                                            ng-model="rowData.statusId"
                                                            class="form-control rowValue"
                                                            id="statusId"
                                                            ng-options='item.id as item.name for item in eventLov.statusOptions()'>
                                                        <option value=''>{{value.name}}</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                    <select ng-if="isObject(value) && key == 'priority'"
                                                            ng-model="rowData.priorityId"
                                                            class="form-control rowValue"
                                                            id="priorityId"
                                                            ng-options='item.id as item.name for item in eventLov.priorityOptions()'>
                                                        <option value=''>{{value.name}}</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                    <select ng-if="isObject(value) && key == 'severity'"
                                                            ng-model="rowData.severityId"
                                                            class="form-control rowValue"
                                                            id="severityId"
                                                            ng-options='item.id as item.name for item in eventLov.severityOptions()'>
                                                        <option value=''>{{value.name}}</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="rowData">Save</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="rowData"
                                            ng-click="cancelForm()">
                                        Cancel
                                    </button>
                                </form>
```

submit changes

```
     $scope.submitForm = function (event) {
                $scope.modifyEvent(event);
                $timeout( function(){
                    $rootScope.refresh();
                }, 100);
            };

 $scope.modifyEvent = function (event) {
                // $log.info(event);
                eventService.modifyEvent(event)
            };
```

update services

```
 function modifyEvent (event) {
           return $http({
               method   : 'PUT',
               url      : apiUrl + event.id,
               data     : event
           }, event)
           .then(function success (result) {
               $log.info("Update Successful");
               return result.data;
           }, function error( err ) {
               $log.error(" update has been failed ", err);
           });
        }
```

refresh grid

```
$rootScope.refresh = function () {

                $log.info("fired");
                eventService.events();
                $scope.$apply();
}
```

refresh services

```
 function events () {
        return $http.get(apiUrl)
                    .then(function (serviceResp) {
                        return serviceResp.data;
                    });
    }
```

in the end I see the error

> $apply already in progress

but data has been uploaded to DB and modified. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$timeout` callback runs during digest:

```
            $timeout( function(){
                $rootScope.refresh();
            }, 100);
```

There's no need to trigger it inside `refresh`. It should be

```
$rootScope.refresh = function () {
                $log.info("fired");
                eventService.events();
}
```

The way to avoid `$rootScope:inprog` errors is to be aware which code runs within digest cycle, and which code doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

**FIX 1 -**

Use

```
$timeout(function(){ 
  $scope.$apply()
  ... write your code here 
},0)
```

It will be triggered when the digest cycle is completed.

**FIX 2 -**

`$scope.$$phase` will return true if the digest cycle is running else false, but it will not be useful in your case as it doesn't provide any callback function.

**Also its not recommended to use**

Answer (score 0):

```
         $rootScope.refresh = function () {

            $log.info("fired");
            eventService.events();
            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.$apply();
            })
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the only one way to force refresh grid and take out the error is to delete scope variable and set it again, @ectus was right when said there is no need to trigger $scope.$apply inside refresh function.
My working code looks like

```
       $rootScope.refresh = function () {
            $log.info("fired");
            $scope.initialData = [];
            getData(urlData);
```

May be there is ugly way, but repeat again there is only one way how to force refreshing grid.

Comment: There's no need to do `delete $scope.initialData`. `$scope.initialData = []` overwrites it.